# Render_plot is failing

Tags: tensorflow-model-analysis

#### System information

- **I have used stock example script provided in TensorFlow Model Analysis**: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/blob/master/docs/tutorials/model_analysis/tfma_basic.ipynb
- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**: Windows 10
- **TensorFlow Model Analysis installed from (source or binary)**: binary using pip install
- **TensorFlow Model Analysis version (use command below)**: 0.41.0, 0.42.0, 0.43.0, 0.44.0 (tried all versions 1-by-1)
- **Python version**: 3.9
- **Jupyter Notebook version**: tried with jupyterlab==3.5.3 as well as 4.0.3
- **Exact command to reproduce**:
  tfma.view.render_plot(
  eval_result,
  tfma.SlicingSpec(feature_values={'trip_start_hour': '1'}))

#### Describe the problem

No plot is being rendered. It fails with below error:
[javascript error while rendering plot via TFMA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/751da.png)

I tried to run the tutorial notebook with several TFMA versions, without any success.
I also tried it on colab, but very first step of TFMA installation itself failed in colab, so I couldn't proceed to generate this error in colab.

Please help. Thanks!!!